# sed and grep get the line number for a match

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a log file and i use sed to extract the lines between two strings which contains the word MATCH. I use sed to extract the lines and grep to only take the lines containing the word "MATCH". I would need the lines number in the log file where a match is found.

```
Date:...
TST STARTS
DISCARD str1
DISCARD str2
MATCH str3 //line 5
MATCH str4 //line 6
DISCARD str5
TST FINISHED
```

I use this command to extract the lines:

```
sed -n "/TST STARTS/,/TST FINISHED/p" log.txt | grep "MATCHED".
```

My output is:

```
MATCH str3
MATCH str4
```

But I also need in the output the lines number:

```
line 5: MATCH str3
line 6: MATCH str4
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use:

```
cat -n
```

to number the lines before you apply your sed, like this:

```
cat -n log.txt | sed -n "/TST STARTS/,/TST FINISHED/p" | grep "MATCHED"
```

Alternatively, you could replace `cat -n` with a variant of `nl`:

```
nl -n ln log.txt | sed ...
```

Comment: the line number inserted with `cat -n` may easily interfere with the operation performed by `sed`, `grep`, etc. at least in the general case.

Answer (score 5):

My first attempt wasn't keeping the line number, because the `sed` part removes certain lines.

Everything can be done with this `awk`:

```
$ awk '/TST STARTS/ {p=1} p && /MATCH/ {print "line "NR" --> "$0}; /TST FINISHED/ {p=0}' a
line 5 --> MATCH str3 //line 5
line 6 --> MATCH str4 //line 6
```

- `'/TST STARTS/ {p=1}` sets a flag `p=1` so that from now on all lines will be taken into account.
- `p && /MATCH/ {print "line "NR" --> "$0}` if the flag `p` is active and the line contains `MATCH`, then it prints the info.
- `/TST FINISHED/ {p=0}` turns the flag off when finding `TST FINISHED` text.

Comment: I need te line number from the original file. In your output: line 5 and 6 instead of line 4 and 5. I did with cat -n. Thanks.

Comment: Oh now I fully understand it, @georgiana_e. Just for completeness, I changed totally my answer so that it really does what is needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n '/TST STARTS/,/TST FINISHED/ {
   /MATCH/ {
      =;p
      }
   }' log.txt
```

line number than the line content on next line

```
| sed "/^[0-9]/ { 
  N
  s/^\(.*\)\n/line \1:/
   }"
```

for inclunding on same line (could be done in 1 sed but huge script and poor performance in this case, event with a recall from shell it's easier with a second sed). 
Could also be don with a previous numbering of line