# awk find between patterns and expand variable

Tags: bash, awk

I have two questions regarding "awk". In a bash script I want to extract the lines that match the word "found" from a file, between two patterns. I use this:

```
awk '/$Pattern START/ {p=1} p && /found/ {print "line_"NR": "$0}; /$Pattern OK/ {p=0}' file2.txt
```

Problems:

```
1. The variable Pattren is not expanded in the syntax presented
2. I want to specify with "or" multiple end patterns something like this:
 awk '/$Pattern START/ {p=1} p && /found/ {print "line_"NR": "$0}; /$Pattern {OK,NOT}/ {p=0}' file2.txt
```

Thanks.

Comment: Variables wouldn't expand within single quotes.

Comment: So you are using the awk command I suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19999013/1983854

Comment: Worked like this: awk '/'$Pattern' START/ {p=1} p && /found/ {print "line_"NR": "$0}; /'$Pattern' OK/ {p=0}' file2.txt

Comment: why `awk` not `grep` ?

Comment: I use awk because i want to get the line number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare variable to use them in `awk`
Here are two example to print all lines that have `home` within them

```
pattern="home"
awk -v pat="$pattern" '$0~pat'
```

```
awk '$0~pat' pat="$pattern"
```

---

For OPs data, it will be:

```
awk -vpat="$Pattern" '$0~pat" START" {p=1} p && /found/ {print "line_"NR": "$0} $0~pat" (OK|NOK)" {p=0}' file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep` and `sed` instead of `awk` in this case :

```
grep "found" file|sed "s/.*pattern1\(.*\)pattern2.*/\1/g"
```

Comment: I also need the line number where the match is found, for that I use awk. I solved the first issue with expanding a variable but remains the second.

Answer (score -1):

Worked this:

```
1. awk '/'$Pattern' START/ {p=1} p && /found/ {print "line_"NR": "$0}; /'$Pattern' OK/ {p=0}' file2.txt
2. awk '/'$Pattern' START/ {p=1} p && /found/ {print "line_"NR": "$0}; /'$Pattern' OK|NOK/ {p=0}' file2.txt
```

Comment: Do not use variable within `awk` code, declare them using `-v`. See my updated post.